# JSON file loading using Data Processor in Informatica

Tags: json, informatica

I am trying to load JSON file with 5 records, the data_processor is loading 25 records. There are no Joiners used in the mapping. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Share some screenshot of the mapping, show some logs - help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the Data Processor created as File Input should be given the file name as the Input in the mapping and a dummy  file with one dummy record should be given in the Session as the Source file. The source file should not be present at both the Mapping level and Session level.